# Android: How to disable debugging to upload the apk

Tags: android, debugging, upload, android-studio

When I try to upload my app in Google Play I get this error.

> Upload failed
>
> You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you
> need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.
> Learn more about debuggable APKs.

I compile my app with Android Studio 0.4.0

I tried to set this in my Manifest.xml - `Android:debuggable="false"` , but nothing happened.
When I tried to set this  `<option name="SOURCE_GEN_TASK_NAME" value="generateReleaseSources" />` in .iml file, and again nothing.

I tried and with this in build.gradle,and again nothing.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("horoskopSms.jks")
            storePassword "1q2w3e"
            keyAlias "horoskopSms"
            keyPassword "1q2w3e"
        }
    }
}
```

My.iml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/.." external.system.id="GRADLE"    type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
<component name="FacetManager">
<facet type="android" name="Android">
  <configuration>
    <option name="SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT" value="debug" />
    <option name="ASSEMBLE_TASK_NAME" value="assembleDebug" />
    <option name="COMPILE_JAVA_TASK_NAME" value="compileDebugJava" />
    <option name="ASSEMBLE_TEST_TASK_NAME" value="assembleDebugTest" />
    <option name="SOURCE_GEN_TASK_NAME" value="generateReleaseSources" />
    <option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
    <option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
    <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/res" />
    <option name="RES_FOLDERS_RELATIVE_PATH" value="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res" />
    <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
    <option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/HoroskopSms-debug-unaligned.apk" />
  </configuration>
</facet>
     <facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
     <configuration>
     <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":HoroskopSms" />
  </configuration>
</facet>
  </component>
           <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="false">
        <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/debug" />
      <exclude-output />
     <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
   <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/r/debug" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/aidl/debug" isTestSource="false" />

<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/buildConfig/debug"         isTestSource="false" />
 <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/rs/debug" isTestSource="false" />
     <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/res/rs/debug" type="java-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/r/test/debug" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/aidl/test/debug" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/buildConfig/test/debug" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/rs/test/debug" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/res/rs/test/debug" type="java-test-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/aidl" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/assets" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/java" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/jni" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/rs" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/res" type="java-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/resources" type="java-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/aidl" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/assets" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/jni" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/rs" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res" type="java-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/aidl" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/assets" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/java" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/jni" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/rs" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/res" type="java-test-resource" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/apk" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/assets" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/bundles" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/dependency-cache" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/incremental" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/libs" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/manifests" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/res" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/symbols" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/tmp" />
</content>
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 19 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
<orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-v4-19.0.0" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71900.aar" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="FortumoInApp-android-9.1.0" level="project" />
</component>
       </module>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found a solution in Android Studio, I go to "Build variants" and change it from debbug to release.

Comment: Just run assembreRelease to achieve it.

Comment: Where is build variants?

Answer (score 5):

There's a `debuggable` property you can set in a build type in your `build.gradle` file; that will supersede any setting in your manifest. You haven't done anything there, have you? The debuggable property of your release build should already be false.

Which build are you trying to upload to Google Play? If you're uploading the debug build, then that's your problem -- upload the release build instead.

Comment: +1 Partly for the answer, partly for being the only person on the internet who knows how to spell "supersede".

Comment: True story, I didn't know how to spell it, but my spellchecker did. Please don't take your vote away.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use the *debug* as BuildVariant to sign and export your apk in Google Play.

You should use the *Release* BuildVariant.
Gradle has some default values, as debuggable that you have to override in your build.gradle (these values override the properties in AndroidManifest).

Change your build.gradle, switch to Release as BuildVariant(on the left edge) and export your apk.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("horoskopSms.jks")
            storePassword "1q2w3e"
            keyAlias "horoskopSms"
            keyPassword "1q2w3e"
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I change it to "release" but again I get the same message from Google Play Developer Console. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Before exporting your apk, you have to choose Realese Build in your BuildVariant dialog (you can find it on the left edge).

Answer (score 2):

this code worked for me

> change  debuggable false and minifyEnabled false insted of true like below code in your app level build.gradle file

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.firstapp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did not configure your gradle correctly. Please check this link please
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations

Answer (score 0):

Open AndroidManifest.xml file

Look for `android:debuggable="true"` under application node.

set it to false

Thank you

Comment: Didn't the OP say *"I tried to set this in my Manifest.xml - Android:debuggable="false" , but nothing happened."*?

Answer (score -1):

On Android studio just Click build then choose Generate Signed Apk...enter your credentials and other info related to your app & then its done.